# Salesforce Global Search API?

Tags: api, global-search

Is there an API that exposes the Salesforce Global Search and replicates the same behavior as global search does?

I have looked at `/services/data/v49.0/Search` and `/services/data/v49.0/parameterizedSearch` endpoints and they don't replicate the same behavior as global search does.

I have even tried `Search.find()` to no avail. Has anyone run into a similar issue? Is there an API enabling GlobalSearch available to us?

For e.g. I want the search I do to be reflected in the SearchActivity object, which happens when I do a global search but not when I use any of the search APIs/methods mentioned above.

I am developing a custom component for the global search for some specific scenarios but want to replicate the behavior and reporting that we get from global search.

Comment: What global search behavior cannot be replicated via these API calls? Please edit your question with these details.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: One more edit, please - what are you trying to achieve? See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: the second edit to add the intention in.